# React create-react-app npm start assistance

Tags: npm

I'm using create-react-app with bluehost and am using npm to start my app. I'm getting a bunch of errors like no package.json found and this is related to npm not being able to find a file. I'm using build production. Any assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first step I would take, is to check your package.json make sure you something similar to this

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "nodemon index.html"
  },
```

This index.html is the script that will be ran when you type npm start. I that is correct, next make sure that you are in your project root when you type npm start.

Edit: Since your error says no package.json file, I would look at option 2 first

Comment: Added what wasn't there and got the same results. Any other ideas.

Comment: I ran npm install and installed successfully. I ran npm start and received a new error saying: npm ERR! brettoconnordesigns@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` & npm ERR! Failed at the brettoconnordesigns@0.1.0 start script.

Comment: {
  "name": "brettoconnordesigns",
  "homepage": "http://git@github.com:caretakerx/brettoconnordesigns.git",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "4.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },

Comment: "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },

Comment: "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/caretakerx/brettoconnordesigns.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "brettoconnordesigns"
  ],
  "author": "Brett O'Connor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/caretakerx/brettoconnordesigns/issues"
  }
}

Comment: @Caretakerx Remove "homepage": "git@github.com:caretakerx/brettoconnordesigns.git",  then try to start your application